# VC vs VB6: Own-Drawn ListBox obvious vestigial while mouse wheel scrolling

Tags: visual-c++, vb6, listbox

On an Own-Drawn ListBox, I select index = 5 then I scrolling down items (let's say going to index 15) by mouse wheel,the item focus of rectangular frame has an annoying appearance with obvious vestigial moving from top to down instead of moving up. Is the own-drawn ListBox a common issue? My VB6 Listbox has such issue,A VC Project on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2877/Owner-Draw-List-Box-with-Icons-and-Text?msg=4984377#xx4984377xx) also has such issue. How to resolve this problem if it is not ListBox feature?

Comment: Note: The Owner-Drawn ListBox is SDK ListBox which created by CreateWindowExW API, then Drarw items in WM_DRAWITEM.

Answer (score 0):

Manifest specifies common controls v6 solved the problem. I feel comfortable now.